# Format Time into appendTable (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with Google Apps Script.

I searched many forums and documentation but I have not found a solution.

I have this code:
 `var tablecell2 = table1row1.appendTableCell([range[i][1]]);`

show: `Sun Aug 19 2012 16:30:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

I want the Time e.g: `16:30:51`

How I do it?

Thanks

raffaele

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is format the date object accordingly. Please check out the [Utilties.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate) function.